# c# add clickable images to gui using code and not the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

i have a folder full of images etc and i want to add them to my gui inside a tab once the program is ran.

steps:

1. read contents inside folder
2. add images to tabcontrol and assign a number to them according to in what order they were added (1) for the first picture added (2) for second etc
3. the images need to be added in rows of 3 with differend x values for every 3 pictures each and 1 y value change for each row of 3

[] [] []

[] [] []

[] []

doesnt need to be divideable in 3 ^ this is fine

my issue is that i didnt even find a way to add images to a gui without using the designer and im fairly new to c# so this is a huge challange for me :(

in AHK i would just gui,add,picture but it doesnt work that way in c#

help or some form of tips/guidance is very appreciated

the reason the pictures need to "have a value" on them is that once they are clicked i know which image was clicked because they should all have their click event be sent to the same function that checks what number that was and changes the value of variables accordingly

thanks for the help SO C# is overwhelming

```
            public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed folder '{0}'.", targetDirectory);
        // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);



        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here. 
    public static void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);
        if (!ImageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path).ToUpperInvariant()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not image");
            return;
        }

        FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        Image i = new Bitmap(path);
        PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
        p.Image = i;
        p.Tag = "im1";
        p.Click += OnImageClick; // this will let you have the same event for all of the pictures
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);
    }



// this is what handles the clicks
private static void OnImageClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hey");
        // I will leave this for you to implement... the 'sender' is the picturebox that was clicked.
        // you can get it back to a PictureBox by casting, like (PictureBox)sender
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Winforms? WPF? ASP.Net? which (if any) are you using?

Comment: you mean, visual *studio*

Comment: Yes please tell me you mean visual studio, visual basic is also a .NET language but is definitely not c#

Comment: i meant studio,sorry XD

Comment: If all have the same Click event you still can tell them apart by looking at the (cast) sender parm.

Comment: @TaW Could you explain further? i have no idea what that means ;)

Comment: @tim_po , I added an example of that to my answer.

Comment: Any event has `object sender` as its first parameter. This points to the Control that has triggered the event. If your images are in Panels or in PictureBoxes their click events can cast the sender back to the right type: `Panel panel = sender as Panel;` You can store any information in the Panel's or the PictureBox's Tag property.. See Drew and Just's answers!

Comment: edited my post ^ how do i change my code properly? i read everyone's answers

Comment: @tim_po see my additional comment, 'f' was supposed to be the FlowLayoutPanel. you would add *that* to your tabcontrol (You can drag one out of the toolbox if you like, or something like `<your tabcontrol>.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(f)` in the code. Not to be rude, but we've given you two pretty complete, separate ways on how to do this, and the rest is up to you. Read up on MSDN as Pseudonym suggested to understand *why* and *how* what we've shown you works and if you need more help, post other, more specific questions here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add images, text, or anything else to a GUI programmatically in Winforms (which is *sounds* like you're using) you'll create an instance of something derived from `Control` and add it to the form's `Controls` ControlCollection. You can use a `FLowLayoutPanel` to give it a grid like view.

```
    // get the list of paths to the files from your directory into an array
    var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Images","*.jpg");

    // create a flowlayout panel
    FlowLayoutPanel f = new FlowLayoutPanel();

    foreach (string path in fileList) 
    {
       Image i = new Bitmap(path);
       PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
       p.Image = i;
       p.Click += OnImageClick; // this will let you have the same event for all of the pictures
       f.Controls.Add(p);
    }

// add the panel to the form
this.Controls.Add(p);

// this is what handles the clicks
private void OnImageClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // I will leave this for you to implement... the 'sender' is the picturebox that was clicked.
            // you can get it back to a PictureBox by casting, like (PictureBox)sender
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

This implementation is quick and dirty: that is, it doesn't handle if the directory isn't found, if there aren't any files in there, etc). It should give you a good idea of where to go. I would recommend reading *a lot* more, getting a book about C# and walking through some examples/tutorials can be immensely helpful. You're right, C# can be overwhelming... that's why Google is your best friend! You don't need to immediately learn how to do everything; I find I learn well by choosing a small-in-scope project that I want to do and learning as I find things that I need.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about the WinForms, the tab control is a dead giveaway I think

Comment: yeah, that was my clue too.

Comment: you are right, you learn when coding something. and thats what im doing right now! i just now noticed that its probably a bit more complicated than i would have imagined. where exacly did you put that code? inside a function?

Comment: just in the comment inside `OnImageClick`. Depending on what you want to do with it, you may need some more 'custom' stuff in that method, or a different way to store the list of images.

Comment: what is f.Controls.Add(p);

Comment: whoops! the `FlowLayoutPanel` was supposed to be 'f' but I initially had written it as 'p'. Fixed it now... it's adding each `PictureBox` to the `Controls` collection of the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: im a bit confused with all the types c# has,i added a FlowLayoutPanel called flowLayoutPanel1 in the right place and use this code:` FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            Image i = new Bitmap(path);
            PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
            p.Image = i;
            p.Tag = "im1";
            p.Click += OnImageClick;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);` end

Comment: i dont have 20 rep :( why is SO limiting new users :(

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that... if you added a panel in the designer (by dragging it) then you can reference that one in your code instead of creating a new one: you don't need the `FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();` line in your code if you added the panel in the designer.

Comment: just put it back then... I can help in chat if you can get 4 more rep but this isn't the place for help like this... you could try posting it on CodeReview

Comment: http://webchat.freenode.net/ could you come to the #ahk channel and ill PM you? :) ty

Comment: sure, DrewJordan in there also.

Answer (score 2):

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article talks about how to get all the filepaths of files in specific directory ("folder")

Their example:

```
// For Directory.GetFiles and Directory.GetDirectories 
// For File.Exists, Directory.Exists 
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

public class RecursiveFileProcessor 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        foreach(string path in args) 
        {
            if(File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This path is a file
                ProcessFile(path); 
            }               
            else if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This path is a directory
                ProcessDirectory(path);
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
            }        
        }        
    }


    // Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories  
    // that are found, and process the files they contain. 
    public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
        string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
        string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here. 
    public static void ProcessFile(string path) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);       
    }
}
```

This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (also MSDN) talks about adding control dynamically at run time, here is their example code:

```
// C#
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
   TextBox myText = new TextBox();
   myText.Location = new Point(25,25);
   this.Controls.Add (myText);
}
```

Finally this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984419%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (again MSDN) article talks about how to set an image from a file, here is their example code:

```
// C#
// You should replace the bolded image 
// in the sample below with an icon of your own choosing.
// Note the escape character used (@) when specifying the path.
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile
   (System.Environment.GetFolderPath
   (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
   + @"\Image.gif");
```

**EDIT:** In the comments it was asked how to wire up a control click event, since we are adding these controls programmatically we need to add the click event programmatically. For demo purposes assume there is a control with id `Button1`, to fire a function when it is clicked you would use code that goes something like this:

```
Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);
```

This will fire the function `myEventHandler` when `Button1` is clicked

So thats a lot of code!

While it may not seem like it, if you look at each piece and consider how they all fit together, this should help you on the right path to (**big hint**), dynamically get a list of images, add an image control to your page, then set that image control to display a specific image, and finally wire up a click event on an image control

Comment: wow, this is amazing, but do these images have a click event connected with them? first ill try to make my program add them but thanks for this <3

Comment: Instead of rolling your own recursive code you can use: Directory.GetFiles(dir, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Comment: @JustFogMaxi Very true! So this is actually the example code for that exact method (check the link), but it is definitely worth pointing out.

Comment: @tim_po no they don't but I will add some more information about how to do that as well

Comment: Added the requested info at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image.Tag property to add extra information to the image.